(VSCode/LaTeX Previewer) Can someone help me figure out why my installation of the plugin doesn't work?
Posted on the VSCode Stack Overflow but since this is a latex plugin I am having trouble with, this should be allowed here.
I have the following LuaLaTeX code that I want to be able to have coupled with the functionality of the LaTeX Previewer addon on Windows
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mhsetup}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{mathtools} % loads amsmath and graphicx
\usepackage{newfloat} % use first over float
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb} % already loads amsfonts
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \newlist{checkboxlist}{itemize}{1}
    \setlist[checkboxlist]{label=$\square$}
    \newlist{alphabetization}{enumerate}{1}
    \setlist[alphabetization]{label=\alph*.)}
    \setlist{nosep}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX, BoldFont=Timesbd.ttf, ItalicFont=Timesi.ttf, BoldItalicFont=Timesbi.ttf]{Times.ttf}
    \setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}
{{\centering
\normalsize{\@title} \\ \smallskip
\normalsize{\@author} \\ \smallskip
\normalsize{\@date} \\ \vspace{\baselineskip}
}}
\makeatother

\AtBeginDocument{%
\setlength\abovedisplayskip{0pt}%
\setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0pt}%
\setlength\belowdisplayskip{0pt}%
\setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0pt}%
}
\showoutput

% Environments And Counters
\newcounter{problemcounter}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{problem}{o}{
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\refstepcounter{problemcounter}}
    {\setcounter{problemcounter}{#1}}
  {\centering \textsc{Problem \arabic{problemcounter}.}\par}}{
}

\newenvironment{solution}{
  {\par \centering \textsc{Solution:}\par}}{
}

\newenvironment{justification}{
  {\centering \textsc{Justification:}\par}}{
}

\setlength\parindent{.25cm} 

%  Commands

\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}

\newcommand{\blk}{\vspace{\baselineskip}}

\title{Homework}
\author{Author}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{problem} % 1

    \begin{solution}
        
    \end{solution}
\end{problem}


\begin{problem} % 2
    
    \begin{solution}
        
    \end{solution}
\end{problem}


\begin{problem} % 3
    
    \begin{solution}
        
    \end{solution}
\end{problem}


\begin{problem} % 4
    
    \begin{solution}
        
    \end{solution}
\end{problem}


\begin{problem} % 5
    
    \begin{solution}
        
    \end{solution}
\end{problem}


\begin{problem} % 6
    
    \begin{solution}
        
    \end{solution}
\end{problem}


\begin{problem} % 7
    
    \begin{solution}
        
    \end{solution}
\end{problem}


\begin{problem} % 8
    
    \begin{solution}
        
    \end{solution}
\end{problem}


\begin{problem} % 9
    
    \begin{solution}
        
    \end{solution}
\end{problem}


\begin{problem} % 10
    
    \begin{solution}
        
    \end{solution}
\end{problem}


\end{document}

What I have installed already: TeX Live, VSCode with LaTeX Workshop, LaTeX Utilities, and Zotaro LaTeX
The instructions for getting the extension setup go like this:

Search for LaTeX Previewer in VS Code Extensions or Open VSX and click Install
Go to the extension settings and set the LaTeX font diretory for your LaTeX distribution e.g. for MiKTeX on Windows C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\fonts or for TeXLive native on Linux /usr/share/texmf/fonts
The system font path will also be searched for font files
Open a LaTeX file and run LaTeX Preview: Show Preview from the Command Palette or click the Preview icon

When I find the font folder inside texmf-local, I click on properties, look at Location and see "C:\texlive\texmf-local". I then copied and pasted this into the box needed as shown in the picture.

Though, when I go to the .TeX file and do Ctrl+Shift+L, it does not show the preview. instead I get this error.
dvilualatex --halt-on-error --interaction=nonstopmode --synctex=-1 c:\Users\Panola\Documents\LuaLaTeX Calculus 1\HomeworkSetter.tex
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.18.0 (TeX Live 2024) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> c:\Users
         \Panola\Documents\LuaLaTeX Calculus 1\HomeworkSetter.tex
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, bad output DVI file produced!
No pages of output.

Error: Command failed: dvilualatex --halt-on-error --interaction=nonstopmode --synctex=-1 c:\Users\Panola\Documents\LuaLaTeX Calculus 1\HomeworkSetter.tex

Could not generate dvi file - review the log for errors.

And when I enable debug mode to enable debug messages, I get a list of windows fonts (all five fonts that I have in the code appear in the list)
Can someone help me figure out why my setup doesn't work? I don't know why this doesn't work, but if someone could help me, it would be a huge help. Thank you for reading. Have a nice day!

This is  a problem with your LaTeX installation and/or the VSC extension which does not know how to treat directories with spaces in it. Probably there should be a better fix, but as a start, try to change the directory name from LuaLaTeX Calculus 1 to, for example, LuaLaTeX_Calculus_1 (no spaces). When interacting with unix-based things, directories (folders) with spaces in the name are normally a call for troubles

BTW, the font directory is clearly wrong. Should be something like C:\texlive\texmf-dist\fonts or whatever you chose as the main installation directory when you installed TeXLive (sorry, no real experience on windows)
